# Question about the Bessel operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, bessel-functions, unbounded-operators

For $\nu>-1$ denote by $\{\lambda_{k,\nu}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ the succesive positive zeros of the Bessel function of the first kind $J_{\nu}$. The  Bessel operator is given by
\begin{equation*}
L_\nu=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{\nu^2-1/4}{x^2}.
\end{equation*}
It is known that functions
\begin{equation*}
\psi_k^\nu(x)=d_{k,\nu}(\lambda_{k,\nu}x)^{1/2}J_\nu(\lambda_{k,\nu}x), \quad d_{k,\nu}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\lambda_{k,\nu}^{1/2}|J_{\nu+1}(\lambda_{k,\nu})|}
\end{equation*}
are eigenfunctions of $L_\nu$ with
$$
L_\nu\psi_k^\nu=\lambda_{k,\nu}^2 \psi_k^\nu.
$$
Moreover, the system $\{\psi_k^\nu\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is orthonormal and complete in $L^2((0,1), dx)$.

The self-adjoint extension of $L_{\nu}$ associated with the Fourier-Bessel system
is defined in $L^2((0,1), dx)$ as
$$
\widetilde{L}_{\nu}f = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda_{k,\nu}^2
    \langle f, \psi_k^{\nu} \rangle \psi_k^{\nu},   
$$
on the domain
$$
\textrm{Dom }  \widetilde{L}_{\nu} = \bigg\{ f \in L^2((0,1), dx) : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}
    \big| \lambda_{k,\nu}^{2} \big\langle f, \psi_k^{\nu}\big\rangle  \big|^2 < \infty \bigg\}.
$$

I would like to show that if $\nu, \alpha>-1$ are such that $\nu\neq\alpha$, then
$$
\textrm{Dom } \widetilde{L}_{\nu}\neq\textrm{Dom } \widetilde{L}_{\alpha}.
$$
I have made some little progress on the above question, but I am not able to settle it fully. I can construct a smooth function $f$ such that
$L_\nu(f)\in L^2$ and $L_\alpha(f)\notin L^2$. Morally, that should imply $f\in\textrm{Dom }\widetilde{L}_{\nu}$ and $f\notin\textrm{Dom } \widetilde{L}_{\alpha}$, but I do not see how to make it rigorous with the above definition of the domain.

I would very much appreciate any hints.

Comment: The argument in your final paragraph ignores boundary conditions, which must be imposed if the domains are described in the usual way. So you need an $f$ with $L_{\nu}f\in L^2$ and satisfying the bc's used to describe $D(L_{\nu})$, and then the argument is fine.

Comment: @ChristianRemling  To address your comments: 1) I am pretty sure that the eigenfunctions are defined correctly. They all come from one fixed Bessel function and differ only by scaling and normalization. This system is described for example in Watson's \textit{Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions} 2) Note that in the definition of $\psi_k^\nu(x)$ there is a factor $\sqrt{x}$, so $|\psi_n^\nu(x)|\simeq x^{\nu+1/2}$, thus $\psi\in L^2$ (since $\nu>-1$) 3) Could you please elaborate on what would be the boundary condition for $D(L_\nu)$? Is it a bc satisfied by functions $\psi_n^\nu$?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Many thanks for your reply!

Comment: @ChristianRemling Would you mind sharing your argument? I would love to see it.

Comment: It's up again. I've deleted/undeleted an embarrassing number of times since I always made computational errors in earlier versions. More precisely, I tried to refute $L$ boundedness of $1/x^2$ by testing on functions cooked up from the solutions of $Lf=0$ (which can be solved explicitly). This is perhaps a fool's errand since one always pays a too high price to force the function into the domain of $L$.

Comment: In particular, I'm not keeping my promise above in the current version. The argument does depend on the $x\to 0$ asymptotics of the eigenfunctions.

Comment: Actually, while this latest version is I hope correct, it is still nonsense in that I can finish the argument in a much easier way. One more edit coming...

Comment: That's very interesting. Thanks a lot for taking your time to write your argument up.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I've been thinking about your first comment and I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between the definition of $\textrm{Dom}  \widetilde{L}_{\nu}$ using the orthogonal system, as stated in my question, and the natural domain described as (correct me if I'm wrong) those $f\in L^2$ for which $ L_\nu f \in L^2$ (in the weak sense) and $f$ satisfies some boundary conditions depending on $\nu$. Would it be true that for any function $f\in \textrm{Dom}  \widetilde{L}_{\nu}\cap C^\infty(0,1)$ (may be singular at 0 or 1) one has $\widetilde{L}_{\nu} f= L_{\nu} f$?

Comment: I think it's best to start out at the other end (so to speak) to describe the situation. For fixed $\nu$, we can define the *maximal operator* $T$ as having this domain, that is those $f\in L^2$ for which $Lf\in L^2$ also. Its adjoint $T_0=T^*$ is symmetric, but not self-adjoint, so there are many self-adjoint realizations (for one and the same $\nu$), conveniently parametrized by boundary conditions at $x=1$ and (if $\nu<1$) $x=0$. Your description in terms of an ONB of eigenfunctions implicitly involves a specific choice of bc's, which could in principle be recovered (cont'd)

Comment: from the eigenfunctions, but which you don't make explicit. Finally, all self-adjoint realizations are restrictions of one and the same maximal operator $T$, so indeed they all act the same on functions that are in several domains simultaneously. These are exactly the functions from $D(T_0)$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you so much for sharing your insights! Your explanation really helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably best to do this by hand, by looking at the domains described in the usual way as those $f$ with $Lf\in L^2$ that satisfy certain boundary conditions at $x=0,1$ (in fact, there will be no boundary condition at $x=0$ when $\nu^2\ge 1$).

But we can also avoid dealing with boundary conditions explicitly, as follows: if we had $D(L)=D(L')$, then $D(L)\subseteq D(M)$, with $M$ denoting the (self-adjoint) operator of multiplication by $1/x^2$ on its natural domain.

But from the behavior of the Bessel functions near $x=0$, we also know that the eigenfunctions of $L$ satisfy $\psi(x)\simeq x^{\nu+1/2}$, so $\psi\in D(M)$ only if $\nu> 1$.

If indeed $\nu\ge 1$, then we transition to limit point case at $x=0$, and no boundary condition is imposed here. It seems possible or even plausible that $D(L)\subseteq D(M)$ now. If this is correct, then $M$ is $L$-bounded, and the bound would drop to values $<1$ if we multiply $M$ by a small constant. Moreover, it cannot get larger if we make $\nu$ larger. That would mean that $D(L)$ is actually constant in the range $\nu>1$.

Comment: When $\nu>1$ it is true that the domain does not change and equals the insersection of the domain of the second derivative and that of the multiplication operator.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Interesting. Is there a quick argument to see this?

Comment: Well, there is an easy argument which give a worse threshold. Call $b=\nu^2- 1/4$ and for $u \in C_c^\infty(0, \infty)$ integrate by parts $Lu=f$ against $u/x^2$. You get $$ \int \left (\frac{u'}{x^2}+\frac{bu^2}{x^4}-2\frac{u u'}{x^3}\right )=\int \frac{uf}{x^2}.$$ Using Cauchy-Schwartz the term with $u, u'$ is dominated by the other two if $b>1$, or $\nu > \sqrt{5}/2$, which is not optimal. To reach $\nu>1$ I need a Rellich type inequality (maybe there is a way to avoid it). I think that Okazawa did first this.

Comment: Of course the above computation does not suffice, alone.

Comment: EDIT (to the previous comment) Using a weighted hardy inequality to estimate the term with $u, u'$ one reaches the optimal value of $\nu$.. If you are interested I can write down the details.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Yes, please. Some details would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question but the main argument to show that the domain is the intersecion between the domain of the second derivative and of the multiplication operator when $\nu>1$. Write $b=\nu^2- \frac 14$ and for $u \in C_c^\infty (0,\infty)$ integrate by parts $Lu=f$ against $x^{-2}u$. One gets
\begin{equation} \label{1}
\int_0^\infty \left (\frac{u'^2}{x^2} +b \frac{u^2}{x^4}-2 \frac{u u'}{x^3}\right )=\int_0^\infty \frac{fu}{x^2} \leq \|f\|_2 \|x^{-2} u\|_2
\end{equation}
and the aim is to estimate the $L^2$ norm of $x^{-2} u$ in terms of $f$ under $b > \frac 34$.
By Cauchy -Schwartz we have $\|x^{-3}u u'\|^2_1 \leq \|x^{-1} u'\|_2 \|x^{-2}u\|_2$ and by Hardy's inequality (see below) $\|x^{-2} u\|_2 \leq \frac 23 \|x^{-1} u'\|_2$. With $A^2=\|x^{-1} u'\|_2^2, B^2=\|x^{-2}u\|_2^2$ the RHS of the displayed equation is bigger than $A^2+bB^2-2AB$. With the constraint $B \leq \frac 23 A$ the quadratic expression above is non-negative for $b \geq \frac 34$, hence dominates $\epsilon B^2$ for $b >\frac 34$ and allows to estimate, by Cauchy-Schwartz again, $B$ in terms of $\|f\|_2$.

Concering the Hardy inequality, I used $\frac u x=\int_0^1 u'(sx)ds$ and take norms with respect to the measure $x^{-2} dx$. By Minkowski inequality (for integrals)
$\|x^{-1} u\|_{L^2(x^{-2} dx)} \leq \int_0^1 \|u'(sx)\|_{L^2(x^{-2} dx)}ds$ and the result follows by simple computations.